# Http PATCH example using HttpUrlConnection?

Tags: java, android

Does anyone have a working PATCH request example using HttpUrlConnection on android? I'm trying something like:

```
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) (new URL(myUrl).openConnection();
conn.setDoOutput(true);
conn.setRequestMethod("PATCH");
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");

OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
wr.write(" {\"name\": \"john\" }");
wr.flush();
```

Thanks

Comment: hey write your solution if you have solved issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HttpURLConnection Invalid HTTP method: PATCH](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25163131/httpurlconnection-invalid-http-method-patch)