# HTTP method PATCH - use with ip and not hostname

Tags: java, http, https, patch

I had a problem of **HttpURLConnection Invalid HTTP method: PATCH**  and got a suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25163131/httpurlconnection-invalid-http-method-patch) in which the **X-HTTP-Method-Override** work around did not work out for me. So I tried

```
CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
HttpPatch httpPatch = new HttpPatch(new URI("http://example.com"));
CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPatch);
```

where I am facing a challenge. My request is an HTTPS request and I have the url as **https://192.168.1.1/foo/bar**. I neither know the hostname of the ip 192.168.1.1 which is validated by **CloseableHttpClient** with the hostname on the certificate, nor want to perform a DNS look up to happen(not even in the known hosts).

Are there any feasibility to perform a PATCH request in my case?

Comment: In what way did the first workaround not work? What error did you get?

Comment: It hits the POST end point which is destined to create a resource and throws resource already exists.