# Want to do a HTTP Request (PATCH)

Tags: java, rest, post

I am trying to do a PATCH Request. Everything works fine in c# but it doesn't work in Java.

The source code:

```
String url = postURL;   
URL obj = new URL(url);

HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

con.setRequestMethod("POST");
con.setRequestProperty("X-HTTP-Method-Override", "PATCH");
con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", authInfo);
con.setRequestProperty("PublicKey", publicKey);
con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", contenttype);

String toPost = "{\"StockQuantity\":"+newVal+"}";

// Send post request
con.setDoOutput(true);
DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
wr.writeBytes(toPost);
wr.flush();
wr.close();

int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + url);
System.out.println("Post parameters : " + toPost);
System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
String inputLine;
StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
    response.append(inputLine);
}
in.close();

System.out.println(response.toString());
```

I get the error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://www.pyewxo-onlineshop.de/odata/ProductVariantAttributeCombination(1757)
>
> **Full Stack trace:**
>
> Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://www.xsadsaaf-onlineshop.de/odata/ProductVariantAttributeCombination(1757)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>     at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$10.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1926)
>     at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$10.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1921)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getChainedException(HttpURLConnection.java:1920)
>     at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1490)
>     at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1474)
>     at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:254)
>     at
>   communication.ServerCommunication.reqPost(ServerCommunication.java:150)
>     at xsadsaaf.xsadsaaf.main(xsadsaaf.java:48) Caused by:
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   https://www.xsadsaaf-onlineshop.de/odata/ProductVariantAttributeCombination(1757)
>     at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1872)
>     at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1474)
>     at
>   java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:480)
>     at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:338)
>     at
>   communication.ServerCommunication.reqPost(ServerCommunication.java:144)
>         ... 1 more
>
> The response code is: 404

With the same url, I can do a request in C#, why not in Java?

Comment: In which line of your code does the `FileNotFoundException` happen?

Comment: Please post full stack trace.

Comment: I can not see the line, where the Exception happens

Comment: Are you sure the header to ovveride the method is supported? (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/40609685/180100)