# How to send restRequest in Patch mode?

Tags: java, http, postman

I'm working with Postman and I see that it has many modes. I was able to implement a restRequest object that "knows" how to send a request in Post or Get method.

This is part of my code:

```
 @Override
public RestResponse sendRequest() {
    return data.accept(new RequestDataVisitor<RestResponse>() {
        @Override
        public RestResponse visit(GetData getData) {
            return new RestResponse(webTarget.request().headers(headers).get());
        }

        @Override
        public RestResponse visit(PostFormData post) {
            return new RestResponse(webTarget.request(post.getMediaType()).headers(headers).post(post.getEntity()));
        }

        @Override
        public RestResponse visit(PostRawData post) {
            return new RestResponse(webTarget.request(post.getMediaType()).headers(headers).post(post.getEntity()));
        }

        @Override
        public RestResponse visit(DeleteData deleteData) {
            return new RestResponse(webTarget.request(deleteData.getMediaType()).headers(headers).delete());

        }
    });
}
```

How do I get my webTarget to send a request in Patch mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was in WebTarget object:

```
WebTarget target = client.target(baseUrl).path(resourcePath)
.property(HttpUrlConnectorProvider.SET_METHOD_WORKAROUND,"true");
```

PATCH method only works when SET_METHOD_WORKAROUND is true.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `method` method with first argument set to "PATCH".

`method` is a generalized method (as opposed to `post`, `get`, `delete` which have the http-method hardwired) and allows you to call an arbitrary method:

```
webTarget.request(mediaType).headers(headers).method("PATCH", entity);
```

See the documentation for additional details: [WebTarget](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/client/WebTarget.html).request gives you an instance of an [Invocation.Builder](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/client/Invocation.Builder.html) which inherits `method` from [SyncInvoker](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/client/SyncInvoker.html).

Note: depending on the JDK version and the JAX-RS library that you are using, you may run into problems when calling the PATCH method. If you do, see if any of these help:

- [PATCH request using Jersey Client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22355235/patch-request-using-jersey-client)
- [HttpURLConnection Invalid HTTP method: PATCH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25163131/httpurlconnection-invalid-http-method-patch))
- [Invalid HTTP method: PATCH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42026770/invalid-http-method-patch)

Comment: Can you please provide a full answer? I get an Exception every time I use your code.