# Getting Error java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun/net/www/protocol/https/HttpsURLConnectionImpl when deployed in Jboss EAP 6.4.x

Tags: java, jboss, http-patch

I am writing a rest client using java.net which should do a PATCH request. But as PATCH is not a supported method in java.net, I used reflection to make it supported by changing the code like

```
private void updateConnectionToSupportPatchRequest(final HttpURLConnection conn)
    throws ReflectiveOperationException {
    try {
        final Object targetConn;
        if (conn instanceof HttpsURLConnectionImpl) {
            final Field delegateField = HttpsURLConnectionImpl.class.getDeclaredField("delegate");
            delegateField.setAccessible(true);
            targetConn = delegateField.get(conn);
        } else {
            targetConn = conn;
        }
        final Field methodField = HttpURLConnection.class.getDeclaredField("method");
        methodField.setAccessible(true);
        methodField.set(targetConn, "PATCH");
    } catch (final NoSuchFieldException ex) {
        LOGGER.error("NoSuchFieldException: {} ", ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

but when I deploy my application which uses my rest client in JBoss, I get this error -

**java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun/net/www/protocol/https/HttpsURLConnectionImpl**

I looked up on this error and came across this post http://planet.jboss.org/post/dealing_with_sun_jdk_related_noclassdeffounderror_under_jboss

I tried the suggested solution in the post still getting the same error. Any ideas on how to get passed this issue?

P.S. I cannot use the Apache HttpClient or RestEasy(Jboss) as there is another 3PP being used in the project which does not support Apache HttpClient

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [using the workaround `X-HTTP-Method-Override`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25163131/httpurlconnection-invalid-http-method-patch) before trying to fiddle with internal classes of the JDK? If that's the case, you can use the instance's `getClass`-method to access fields and use `isAssignableFrom` as alternative to `instanceof`.

Another approach to get rid off specifying concrete classes is just trying to get the field in `HttpsURLConnection` and assuming a non-Https-URLConnection if the field can't be found. This might look like the following code:

```
private void updateConnectionToSupportPatchRequest(final HttpURLConnection conn) 
    throws ReflectiveOperationException {
    try {
        final Object targetConn = conn;
        try {
            final Field delegateField = findField(conn.getClass(), "delegate");
            delegateField.setAccessible(true);
            targetConn = delegateField.get(conn);
        }
        catch(NoSuchFieldException nsfe) {
            // no HttpsURLConnection
        }
        final Field methodField = findField(conn.getClass(), "method");
        methodField.setAccessible(true);
        methodField.set(targetConn, "PATCH");
    } catch (final NoSuchFieldException ex) {
        LOGGER.error("NoSuchFieldException: {} ", ex.getMessage());
    }
}

private Field findField(Class clazz, String name) throws NoSuchFieldException {
    while (clazz != null) {
        try {
            return clazz.getDeclaredField(name);
        }
        catch(NoSuchFieldException nsfe) {
            // ignore
        }
        clazz = clazz.getSuperclass();
    }
    throw new NoSuchFieldException(name);
}
```

But this might fail at another level because - obviously - the class that is used within JBoss is not the one you implemented the workaround, so fields and methods might be named differently.

Comment: Yes, I have tried "X-HTTP-Method-Override" but still underneath, it sends a POST and I get back a 405 error.
I tried your suggestion of using isAssignableFrom but still getting the same error :- java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun/net/www/protocol/https/HttpsURLConnectionImpl