# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun/net/www/protocol/https/DefaultHostnameVerifier

Tags: java, java-module

I'm moving a Java Swing app for which I do not have the source from Java 8 to Java 10.

I first ran into:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/ws/WebServiceException
```

Which I successfully solved. As explained in [many posts on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43574426/how-to-resolve-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javax-xml-bind-jaxbexception-in-j) and other sites, modules have been moved out of the JDK as of Java 9. This means I had to bring back dependencies into my classpath for the app to run.

Now I am getting:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun/net/www/protocol/https/DefaultHostnameVerifier
```

But I cannot seem to find where that dependency is. I found a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47135808/getting-error-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-sun-net-www-protocol-https-httpsur) which suggested changing code but that is not an option for me. What else can I try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sun` package classes were always meant as internal JDK implementation detail and not meant to be used in the application code. Now that JDK was modularized by [Project Jigsaw](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/) this class is no longer available and that's a good thing. This is not anything new, see [Why Developers Should Not Write Programs That Call 'sun' Packages](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-sun-packages-142232.html):

> The sun.* packages are not part of the supported, public interface.
>   A Java program that directly calls into sun.* packages is not guaranteed to work on all Java-compatible platforms. In fact, such a program is not guaranteed to work even in future versions on the same platform.

The solution is to change your application code to be compatible with JDK 10. If your application code can't be changed it should remain on JDK 8.

Comment: I was afraid I might hear this - the other posts were leaning that way. Thanks for confirming.

Comment: @DavidBrossard check what tries to load this class, if it's a 3rd party library you might get away with updating the library