# Microprofile - Invalid HTTP method: PATCH

Tags: java, rest, http, patch, microprofile

During my development I had to invoke an API with the PATCH method, so I write the following interface:

```
import javax.enterprise.context.Dependent;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.PATCH;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

import org.eclipse.microprofile.rest.client.inject.RegisterRestClient;

@Dependent
@RegisterRestClient
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public interface SimpleServiceMicroprofileApi {

    @PATCH
    @Path("api/sample/greet")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public PojoEntity recallGreet(PojoEntity patch);
}
```

When I try to invoke recallGreet method is thrown a javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: java.net.ProtocolException: **Invalid HTTP method: PATCH** (log below).

After some investigation, it seems that problem is caused by [HttpsURLConnection implementation and there exists some workarounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25163131/httpurlconnection-invalid-http-method-patch) which does not solve my problem. I had to use an apache client to invoke this API...
Is there any trick for this method?

I create a [sample project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ab005zsex5b6ihu/patch.zip?dl=0) with this problem, just deploy it and invoke http://localhost:8080/micro-sample/api/micro/recallGreet.

Also opened an [issue](https://github.com/eclipse/microprofile/issues/87) with this behavior on microprofile repository.

====================== Log ====================

```
2019-01-29T11:43:18.979+0000|Info: micro-sample was successfully deployed in 2,541 milliseconds.
2019-01-29T11:43:33.156+0000|Severe: javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: java.net.ProtocolException: Invalid HTTP method: PATCH
javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: java.net.ProtocolException: Invalid HTTP method: PATCH
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.internal.HttpUrlConnector.apply(HttpUrlConnector.java:284)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRuntime.invoke(ClientRuntime.java:286)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.lambda$invoke$2(JerseyInvocation.java:788)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:316)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:298)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:229)
at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:414)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.invoke(JerseyInvocation.java:786)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.method(JerseyInvocation.java:469)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.proxy.WebResourceFactory.invoke(WebResourceFactory.java:331)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy350.recallGreet(Unknown Source)
at fish.payara.micro.sample.MicroService.recallGreet2(MicroService.java:28)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor236.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:45005)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.lambda$static$0(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:76)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:148)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:191)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$TypeOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:243)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:103)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:493)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:415)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:104)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:277)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:272)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:268)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:316)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:298)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:268)
at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:289)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:256)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:704)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:416)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:370)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:389)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:342)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:229)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1628)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:258)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.__invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:40002)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:755)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:575)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:159)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:371)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:238)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:520)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:217)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:182)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:156)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:218)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:95)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:260)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:177)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:109)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:88)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:53)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:524)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:89)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:94)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:33)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:114)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:569)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:549)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.net.ProtocolException: Invalid HTTP method: PATCH
at java.net.HttpURLConnection.setRequestMethod(HttpURLConnection.java:440)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.setRequestMethod(HttpURLConnection.java:552)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.internal.HttpUrlConnector._apply(HttpUrlConnector.java:342)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.internal.HttpUrlConnector.apply(HttpUrlConnector.java:282)
... 65 more
```