# Sending a PATCH request from Swagger api-client

Tags: rest, spring-boot, jax-rs, swagger, swagger-codegen

I am using spring boot 1.5, Swagger client api(not rest template) for making calls to source.

I am using the PATCH approach for partial updates, and had no problem creating a server side annotation and implementation for this.

However, when I try to write client code for testing, it fails.

Invalid HTTP method: PATCH; nested exception is java.net.ProtocolException: Invalid HTTP method: PATCH

Interestingly, when our applications are deployed in docker, It works but in local it fails with above error.

We have the same problem with integration tests

Not sure if I am missing on something? Is it the problem with spring boot?

Its spring boot microservices.

We use `codegen (group: 'io.swagger', name: 'swagger-codegen-cli', version: '2.3.0-SNAPSHOT', classifier: 'HATEOAS') { transitive = false }` in source to generate client api.

Import api client in consumer service like

```
compile(group: 'com.xy.xy', name: 'product-service', version: '0.1.1', classifier: 'clientApi')
```

To make a patch call we use

```
productControllerApi.updateProductAssociationUsingPATCH(id, unitIds);
```

Comment: How do you test your API? Can you share your client code?

Comment: @BunyaminCoskuner Its spring boot microservices.

We use codegen (group: 'io.swagger', name: 'swagger-codegen-cli', version: '2.3.0-SNAPSHOT', classifier: 'HATEOAS') { transitive = false } in source to generate client api.

Import api client in consumer service using

compile(group: 'com.xy.xy', name: 'product-service', version: '0.1.1', classifier: 'clientApi')

To make a patch call we use

productControllerApi.updateProductAssociationUsingPATCH(id, unitIds);

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25163131/113116) help?

Comment: @Helen It doesn't help because I don't want to manually set the url. I just want to use client api. If I use RestTemplate.setRequestFactory(new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory() and use RestTemplate.exchange, its working. Just that the client-api is having the problem. That too in local and integration tests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom API client class extended from `ApiClient` with the overridden `buildRestTemplate` which sets request factory `HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory`, and pass it through swagger-generated API class constructors when creating an object.

```
import org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

import io.swagger.client.ApiClient;

public class CustomApiClient extends ApiClient {

    @Override
    protected RestTemplate buildRestTemplate() {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        restTemplate.setRequestFactory(new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory());
        return restTemplate;
    }

}
```

When instantiating the API classes, don't use the default constructor, because, it uses the default `ApiClient` class, but you need a custom one with a custom rest template instance. So using the constructor with the parameter of `ApiClient` will solve the issue.

```
@Test
void testApiMethod() {
  TestApi testApi = new TestApi(new CustomApiClient());
}
```