# NativeScript + http PROPFIND method in android : is it possible?

Tags: nativescript, webdav, propfind

I'm working on a contacts app on NativeScript, so I need to connect to a webdav server with PROPFIND method. 
I'm working on Android.
Eveything works on a node project, **but in NativeScript I can't manage to get an answer from my PROPFIND request**.

I tried with 3 different methods, each of them being OK in node and KO in nativescript. UPDATE : I also tried on React Native, and it worked like a charm.

My results in NativeScript :

*core HTTP from nativescript* :

"HTTP erreur Error: java.net.ProtocolException: Expected one of [OPTIONS, GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE, TRACE, PATCH] but was PROPFIND"

*axiox* :

"Error: Request failed with status code null"

*Fetch* :

"TypeError: Network request failed"

If I change the method (GET or POST instead of PROPFIND), I receive "normal" http errors related to the face that it's not the good method.

--> could it be a dead end with Native Script ? I hope there is a way to bypass this and use webdav methods in Native Script ! 
Thanks++.

Comment: The error does seem to suggest that this is a problem with the client. There are many more HTTP methods than just those 7 so it's strange they limited it.

Comment: I think it's Android / Java issue, couple workarounds are discussed in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25163131/httpurlconnection-invalid-http-method-patch

Answer (score 0):

Use this plugin - https://market.nativescript.org/plugins/@klippa/nativescript-http/ in place of the core nativescript http module. This is supposed to be a drop-in replacement for the core HTTP and custom methods like 'PROPFIND' work with it (at least for now).